# Using Apache Camel with Netty to just redirect tcp messages, with no transformation

Tags: java, apache-camel, netty

I could use Netty alone to redirect TCP messages from one port to another. I was guided through this site >> http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/netty/use-netty-to-proxy-your-requests. Now I want to use Apache Camel with Netty to do the same thing. But looks like there is some configurations I am missing on the parameters when I redirect to the second port. My Router is like below. When I try to connect the iscsi initiator(client) from port 3260, my target(server) at port 3261 is listening, but it does not respond correctly. Does any one have any hint about what parameters should I use. I already tried no parameters or only sync=true/false but with no success. I believe there is some thing to do not messy with the tcp messages.

```
package org.camel.netty.first.server;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.spring.Main;

public class ServerRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.setApplicationContextUri("META-INF/spring/app-context.xml");
        main.run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("netty:tcp://localhost:3260?sync=false&allowDefaultCodec=false&encoder=#stringEncoder&decoder=#stringDecoder")
                .to("netty:tcp://localhost:3261?sync=false&allowDefaultCodec=false&encoder=#stringEncoder&decoder=#stringDecoder");
    }
}
```

Using netty4. from("netty4:tcp://localhost:3260?sync=true&allowDefaultCodec=false").to("netty4:tcp://localhost:3261?sync=true&allowDefaultCodec=false"); Seems it is necessary to create a safe pool.

```
WARNING: Failed to release a message: SimpleLeakAwareByteBuf(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(freed))
io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0, decrement: 1
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:101)
    at io.netty.buffer.WrappedByteBuf.release(WrappedByteBuf.java:820)
    at io.netty.buffer.SimpleLeakAwareByteBuf.release(SimpleLeakAwareByteBuf.java:34)
    at io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.release(ReferenceCountUtil.java:59)
    at io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.safeRelease(ReferenceCountUtil.java:84)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.remove(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.failFlushed(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:473)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:709)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:315)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:676)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1059)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:688)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1600(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:32)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:992)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:924)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:380)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Apr 04, 2016 2:59:15 PM io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil safeRelease
WARNING: Failed to release a message: UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(freed)
io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0, decrement: 1
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:101)
    at io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.release(ReferenceCountUtil.java:59)
    at io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.safeRelease(ReferenceCountUtil.java:84)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.remove(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.failFlushed(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:473)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:709)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:315)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:676)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1059)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:688)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1600(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:32)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:992)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:924)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:380)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Not all http traffic are strings

Comment: Please elaborate on "does not respond correctly". Is there an error or just an unexpected response?  Also, try inserting a route step in between that displays the message going across to make sure it's what you expect.
Lastly, try using Netty4: http://camel.apache.org/netty4.html

Comment: I tried to use netty4. It seems I have to create a safe pool.

Comment: Were you able to get this setup working?